# vue-drag-drop: context on target of drop event

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

This is probably a really naive question that is less about vue-drag-drop and more about vuejs, which I'm new to.

If I have two lists of stuff:

```
<ul>
    <li v-for="thing in thing">
        <drag :transfer-data="{ thing }">
            <span>{{ thing.title }}</span>
        </drag>
    </li>    
</ul>

<ul>
    <li v-for="day in days">
        <drop @drop="handleDrop" ref="day"></drop?
    </li>
</ul>
```

In the *handleDrop()* method I can see the event, which include what was dragged into the list item, but I don't see how I have any context on which item in the array the dragged thing was dragged *into*.  I tried using a *ref* on the *drop* element, but that didn't seem to be what I wanted.

How do I know which *day* the item was dragged into?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I missed something, but wouldn't `this` in `handleDrop()` be the component that was dropped onto? That's how it is for other event handlers in Vue.

See [here for an example](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Method-Event-Handlers):

```
<div id="example-2">
  <!-- `greet` is the name of a method defined below -->
  <button v-on:click="greet">Greet</button>
</div>
```

```
var example2 = new Vue({
  el: '#example-2',
  data: {
    name: 'Vue.js'
  },
  // define methods under the `methods` object
  methods: {
    greet: function (event) {
      // `this` inside methods points to the Vue instance
      alert('Hello ' + this.name + '!')
      // `event` is the native DOM event
      if (event) {
        alert(event.target.tagName)
      }
    }
  }
})

// you can invoke methods in JavaScript too
example2.greet() // => 'Hello Vue.js!'
```

#### Update

The above is true, but you want to know which `day` is that `drop` component. To achieve that, [pass it as a prop to the child](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-to-Child-Components-with-Props) `drop` component like so:

```
Vue.component('drop', {
  props: ['day'],
  // ...
})
```

```
<ul>
    <li v-for="day in days">
        <drop @drop="handleDrop" ref="day" :day="day"></drop>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The `:day="day"` is the key. Then, in `handleDrop()`, `this.day` will be the day

Comment: The 'this' would be the vue instance, but I don't want to know the view instance.  I want to know where in the element hierarchy the item was dropped.  When the vue includes an array of items that can receive drop events, I'd like to know which one is getting the drop.

Comment: @voodoogiant now I think I understand. Please see my update

Answer (score 0):

I figured out I need to pass the data myself.  One way to do this is to wrap the function vue-drag-drop provides.

```
<ul>
    <li v-for="day in days">
        <drop @drop="function(data, event) { handleDrop(data, day, event); }" ref="day"></drop>
    </li>
</ul>
```

That seems to work as expected, but I'm wondering if there's another way to do it like using a library attribute (similar to *ref*).